# asp.net webapi 2 attribute routing not working

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have visual studio 2012 installed with mvc4 using .net framework 4.5. Now I want to use webapi2 with attribute writing and i want my hlep page show all the endpoints properly.

In my solution i added a new mvc4 base emtpy project and using nuget i upgraded to mvc5 and then i have installed webapi2 packages. lastly i have installed help package for webapi2.

now when i use routeprefix I cant see any content on help page and when i try to access my webapi endpoint in browsers it throws following error.

http://expressiis.com/api/v1/

```
   <Error>
    <Message>
    No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://expressiis.com/api/v1/'.
    </Message>
    <MessageDetail>
    No type was found that matches the controller named 'v1'.
    </MessageDetail>
    </Error>

namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/v1")]
    public class SubscribersController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/<controller>   
        [Route("")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" }.AsQueryable();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Based on your information, it looks like you are not calling the `httpConfig.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` (Make sure to call this *before* any traditional routing registrations)

Since you haven't called MapHttpAttributeRoutes, your request seems to be matching a traditional route, for example, like `api/{controller}`. This will not work because routes matching traditional routes will never see controllers/actions decorated with attribute routes.

Comment: inside my webapiconfig.cs i have this code now config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
but it gives me following error now The object has not yet been initialized. Ensure that HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized() is called in the application's startup code after all other initialization code.

Comment: Right, that error message is expected and you would need to change your existing call of `WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)` to `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);` to fix it. Basically `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);` internally calls `EnsureInitialized` for you.

Comment: yeah i haev found another answer to fix that issue everything is working thanks for your time. your awsome

Comment: I was struggling with MvcRoutes and WebApiRoutes for so long, this is the answer! `MapHttpAttributeRoutes` has to be before the `MapMvcAttributeRoutes`! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I had attribute routing only enabled. No convention based routing. Everything is set up as you say. It doesn't work. Btw I have implemented many webapi projects. I mean I am not novice in this. I just work with .net core these days and I don't know if I am missing something from the old days

Answer (score 35):

A problem I ran into was related to the ordering in Application_Start(). Note the order of Web API configuraton below:

This does NOT work

```cs
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
}
```

This does work

```cs
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Comment: Thanks...moving the line 'GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register)' to be above 'RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)' worked for me.

Comment: I bet this has to do with OWIN and GlobalConfiguration in the same app. I updated an MVC4 app to MVC5 + OWIN and this happened. But this doesn't happen with my fresh MVC5 +OWIN app which has an Application_Start() containing only filter, route, and bundle config setups. No GlobalConfiguration.Configure call. And it works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, this one had me stumped for ages!

Answer (score 25):

I had this problem too and after a long search I realized that I was using `System.Web.Mvc.RouteAttribute` instead of `System.Web.Http.RouteAttribute`
After correcting this and using `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes() everything worked fine.`

Comment: I had the same problem. If your controller is inheriting Controller instead of ApiController then you are most likely using the MVC versions instead of the Http ones.

Comment: Great stuff. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Saved me hours and hours. Thanks

Comment: Definitely a viable issue; and one to note when you are following the other advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

This was not your case (as is apparent from your sample code), but please do remember to end the Controller class name with `Controller`.

Else it won't be picked up by `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`.

Comment: Thanks.  Saved me in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67925370/web-api-2-attribute-routing-not-working-in-4-5-webforms-project

Comment: Holy cow you don't know how much frustration you just saved me. Hours of debugging just to find this.

Answer (score 5):

This question already has a selected answer. But I had a different solution for myself and think it would be helpful to reply if the selected answer doesn't help.

For me it was a silly mistake. I had two controllers but only one was working. The solutions was that my controller class was named improperly!

My working controller-

```
public class FooController : ApiController { }
```

My non-working controller-

```
public class BarControllers : ApiController { }
```

Be sure your controller class ends in `Controller`. The trailing `s` got me!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't have two controllers with the same name! I was moving some controllers from one assembly I was throwing away into the website... whilst the website no longer had references to the old assembly other assemblies did which meant it was copied in to the WebSite bin folder. The route discovery process then seemed to fail silently when it came across two occurrences of the same controller!

Comment: Even if the controllers are in a different namespace, if they have the same class name, this seems to break attribute routing.

Comment: Just had this happen when adding an API project alongside an existing MVC one and ending up with Controllers in both with the same names -- Attribute Routing completely and inexplicably broken

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was missing full custom path in attributes. I was writing only custom action name without 'api/'. So that was my mistake. My scenario was, 
WebApiConfig template code:

```
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

my incorrect way of route

```
[RoutePrefix("myapps")]  // wrong code
public class AppsController : BaseRestAPIController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("getapps")]
    public ResponseData GetAppList()
    {
```

Correct way

```
[RoutePrefix("api/myapps")]  // correct way. full path start from 'api/'
public class AppsController : BaseRestAPIController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("getapps")]
    [Route("api/myapps/getapps")] // you can use full path here, if you dont want controller level route
    public ResponseData GetAppList()
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, VS create my controller with the name

```
TestController1
```

I dont know why he put this number "one" in the end of name, but remove and will work.

Answer (score -5):

In my case following line was creating problem, just commented it and everything start working

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

Comment it in WebApiConfig.cs file