# Web API 2 Attribute Routing Not Working in 4.5 WebForms Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-web-api2

I've seen many other questions that are similar to my title but none seem to be same issue or supply insight that I need.

I've added a Web API Controller to an existing, legacy 4.5 WebForms application and am trying to get it working with minimal changes to existing code base.  So I don't have the typical static `WebApiConfig` class and other default created items when you create project from scratch.  My existing code base is:

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Start( Object sender, EventArgs e ) 
{ 
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure( config =>
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new
            {
                id = RouteParameter.Optional
            }
        );
    } );
}
```

**Controller**

```
namespace Modeler.Endpoints
{
    public class KatAppEndpoints : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route( "api/katapp/calculations" )]
        public IEnumerable<string> GetCalculations()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("api/katapp/calculations")
        .done(function () { debugger; })
        .fail(function (_jqXHR, errorStatus, errorMessage) { debugger; })
        .always(function () { debugger; });
});
```

When called, I hit the `fail` and `always` and the result is:

> errorStatus: "error"
> errorMessage: "Not Found"

Anything obvious I'm missing?

**Update**

If instead I change my Controller to...

```
namespace Modeler.Endpoints
{
    public class KatAppsController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
}
```

And my javascript to:

```
$.getJSON("api/katapps")
    .done(function () { debugger; })
    .fail(function (_jqXHR, errorStatus, errorMessage) { debugger; })
    .always(function () { debugger; });
```

Things work correctly.  However, I have a handful of endpoints and wanted to use Attributes, but maybe I'll give up on that if I can figure out how to get another portion in the url (i.e. the /calculations part from above).

Comment: Are you using HTTP or HTTPS?  If server want HTTPS and you are sending HTTP that could cause this issue.  Most server these days want HTTPS.  With 4.5 some  still used HTTP.

Comment: Local dev, so yes, HTTP while developing/testing.  Is there a way to allow HTTP?

Comment: If you debug, do you even hit the ````GetCalculations()```` function?

Comment: No, I never get into `GetCalculations()`.  See my update to the question about some more info.

Comment: The server has settings like require https.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why, but this comment pointed me in the right spot:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/38130308/166231

So even though I want to use attribute routing and might not be close to what controller name is, I still have to end the class name with `*Controller`.  After renaming `KatAppEndpoints` to `KatAppEndpointsController`, everything worked.